# Does this free antivirus capable to block worm attacks?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Does this free antivirus capable to block worm attacks?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42825/does-this-free-antivirus-capable-to-block-worm-attacks)

Answer (score 2):

Questions about applications, protocols above OSI layer-4, and hosts are off-topic on [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/). These types of questions can be asked on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) for a business network, or on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) for a personal network.

The [Help/On-Topic](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page will explain what is or is not on-topic. Each SE site has such a page, and you should check the page before asking a question on the site.